# Does window.onload pause the script or simply awaits till value is true and runs the statement?

Tags: javascript, onload

Out of curiosity if I am using for example.

```
window.onload = function() {
    testFunction();
};

function testFunction() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}
```

Does this pause the script or simply waits till the window load value is true and run the statement? I am sure its the latter but to better understand script behavior I was curious to find answer with more knowledgeable coders.

Comment: It's an event handler, so it waits for the event to happen and does not halt the script execution in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.onload = ...` is just an assignment: it stores a function in the window.onload variable. When an event happens, the JavaScript engine looks at the corresponding onsomething property and runs the function assigned to that variable. In fact, this would be valid as well:

```
function testFunction() {
    alert("Hello World!");
}

window.onload = testFunction;
```

The same thing is true for functions bound with the addEventListener function.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    // do something
});

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    // do something else
});
```

This simply adds functions to an underlying list of functions which will be called when the load event happens. This is required when you need to bind multiple events to the same object.

Comment: That makes sense and actually I think my question is flawed in that the alert wouldn't need to listen for the onload event as its my understanding the onload is basically used to make sure all elements of the DOM are present before beginning. 

In theory my function runs once already and then is ran again on the onload, would this be correct?

So I'm guessing the example would have been more appropriate in conjuction with a getElementById reference than the alert function?

Comment: @JamesJohnson I don't get your question about getElementById - sure, you can attach an event listener to an element. Fully depends on that you intent to achieve.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Well, it was just an example so it didn't really matter, but you're right. The onload event is useful if you want to make sure the page is done loading before doing something which manipulates the DOM. In the case of an `alert` call, all it does is make sure the page is loaded before showing the message (so you'll see the page under the popup instead of a white screen).

Answer (score 1):

It's an event listener.

See documentation here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

and here:http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

You might like to try the Visual Event extension for Chrome. It shows you all event listeners that are currently attached to the page displayed.

Comment: Yeah and I see that my example is also flawed as the alert wouldn't really need an event listener such making sure the page is load before running. The function itself does run once though correct? Then it runs again once the event listener is found to be true? BTW, the Visual Event extension for Chrome was an awesome share, thanks!

Comment: @JamesJohnson The onload event handler runs once only and thus your function is called one only. In case your code does unexpected things (telling from what you write the function runs twice), I suggest you post a jsfiddle and someone will have a look at it. Note that there are some frameworks which do come call event handlers several times that one would expect to be called just once.

Comment: Correct, in that the event listener only runs once because once true it is not needed anymore. But if scripts are ran line by line then what I was saying was the function itself would run but it may not be valid yet as the DOM isn't fully loaded. In this case it would run again once the event listener is activated. The reference to a getElementById was to show in the case that my script ran but the element node wasn't loaded yet which would make the function do nothing.

Comment: @JamesJohnson Functions are only executed when they are called directly. So there's no execution of a function just because a javascript parser (i.e. browser) came across it.

Comment: Well that make sense and why I digress to people of better understanding than me ;). So my function is literally just a placeholder of code that is dormant unless I run a specific call to the function explicitly or by an event that is in my script.